# Performance of Grakn match query is extremely slow on nearly empty graph

Tags: vaticle-typedb

(Using the latest version of Grakn community)

I have a graph with some rules and entities, of which one entity type is mostly isolated (not part of any relations but does act a role).

I’ve defined this entity type, user, below:

```
containment sub relation,
  relates container,
  relates containee;

uuid sub attribute, value string;
last-seen sub attribute, value datetime;

user sub entity,
  has uuid,
  has last-seen,
  plays containee;
```

The attributes are only owned by user. I currently have 5 user instances in my graph that I put in for testing, and when I run match queries I get severely degraded performance.

For example, consider the following query:

```
match $u isa user, has uuid "test"; get; offset 0; limit 1;
```

This query clocks in at ~100 calls over a 30 second period, which IMO is extremely slow considering how often we might want to get a very specific user from the database. More complex queries that involve querying the user with relations are exponentially slower.

Timing it, even with a nearly empty graph it's still faster to run a find-populate in Mongo. With a larger graph of say 100 relations, it's not even a contest as the Grakn query can take several minutes to return.

However, it takes less than a second to complete 2000 insert queries (without match clauses).

This doesn't seem to make any sense to me as Grakn is a graph database optimized for graphs and should also resolve transitive closures faster, and yet even with a shallow empty graph it seems to be struggling with queries. I assume there is something wrong with my schema or query.

This leads me to believe there is some aspect of my entity definition or syntax that is resulting in very slow match queries. I’m wondering where to even begin looking (or if this is actually expected speed)?

Answer (score -1):

not sure what was the cause of that slowness, but feel free to test out Grakn 2.0 (completely rewritten from scratch, for performance) - the alpha version is out now (missing some things such as rules), and the full version will be out soon!